# what is the installation size of vim?

Tags: installing

How much space does vim take up in for example Ubuntu 18.04.1? I'm not sure how to check, I don't want to `apt purge` and then install again

Comment: `apt show vim` ?

Comment: just the binary or all files that come with the installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I build my own Vim (Version 8.1) from the sources and install it to a custom directory. The build is with feature "huge", so a lot of features are compiled in. This installs around 37 MB (including runtime files, help files, man page in different languages, ...).

If you install from deb packages it depends on the packages you install. Installing the package "vim" would also install the dependencies "vim-common" and "vim-runtime". This gives you:

```
> apt show vim vim-common vim-runtime | grep Installed-Size:
Installed-Size: 2.458 kB
Installed-Size: 377 kB
Installed-Size: 27,5 MB
```

Note that this is on Ubuntu 16.04 and the installed version of Vim is 7.4. Check on your own machine.